# Can a brand-new iPhone be stored in its box long-term?

Tags: iphone, battery

I purchased an iPhone SE last year but still haven’t opened it. Is it safe to leave an iPhone unopened in its box long-term (at room temperature if that makes a difference) without any negative consequences?

From what I understand, the question

[Before putting an iPhone5 into very long-term storage should I fully drain battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310978/before-putting-an-iphone5-into-very-long-term-storage-should-i-fully-drain-batte)

discusses about an iPhone that has already been used (and the inquiry is about placing it in long-term storage), whereas mine is asking about a brand-new iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have not charged the battery, leaving the unit in the box for long-term storage should pose no difficulty. Batteries as supplied from the manufacturer are holding about 50% charge, which is the ideal amount of charge for lithium batteries to be left in storage.

Comment: Than answers my question perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @JimmyVailer If you're happy with the answer, please consider flagging my answer as accepted. That makes the answer more visible to other users who have the same question. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I was intending to do so. However, the site is making me wait 5 more min first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JimmyVailer Making you wait? Good grief! 

Comment: @TraneFrancks “more visible”? Or does it mark the q&a complete so the “community” script does not keep bouncing it to the top... any search I have done finds answers both accepted and not accepted...

Comment: @SolarMike It's the difference between a white answer box (unaccepted) and a green one (accepted). Some of us only visit questions for which an answer has yet to be accepted as a solution. YMMV and all that. :)